# The The function should return a String that contains the city, a comma and a space, the state, a space, and the zipcode

Tags: javascript, function, return

Write a simple JavaScript function named makeLocation with three parameters named city, state, and zipcode. The function should return a String that contains the city, a comma and a space, the state, a space, and the zipcode. For example, if the function were called like this:

```
var region = makeLocation("San Francisco", "CA", "94129");
```

it would return "San Francisco, CA 94129" without the double quotes.

Please check my code:

```
var region = function makeLocation("city", "state", "zipcode"){
return "city" + ', ' + "state" + " " + "zipcode";
}
```

Comment: `"city"` is a string, you want it to be an *identifier* (`city`), also you are only asked to declare a function, so remove the `var region = `

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding quotes to your variables? Also why are you creating a named function, then assigning it to a differently named variable? Looks like you need to read a bit more on the fundamentals of JavaScript.

```
function makeLocation(city, state, zipcode) {
  return '' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zipcode;
}
var region = makeLocation('Logan', 'UT', '84321');
console.log(region);
// Outputs: Logan, UT 84321
```